kubernetes pod won't start unless I rename the azure disk
I encountered a strange behaviour concerning my Azure kuberentes pod.
This is a postgres db disk.
My pod crashes only if I choose a specific (the original) name for the disk
Using the same snapshot by creating another  disk with a different name the pod will be available.
Why does the disk name matter at all? Is it cached somewhere?
kubectl get pods

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  22s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/appsdevjiradb to aks-mynode-38030476-1
  Normal   Pulled     5s (x3 over 22s)  kubelet            Container image "appsacr.azurecr.io/jiradb:jiradb-14.4-0607" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5s (x3 over 22s)  kubelet            Created container appsdevjiradb
  Normal   Started    5s (x3 over 22s)  kubelet            Started container appsdevjiradb
  Warning  BackOff    3s (x2 over 20s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container dbpod in pod dbpod_default(30039926-dd7a-4583-8f5b-82f5a6839149)

Do you have any idea what else I can check?
This my yaml file:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jiradb
  labels:
    name: jiradb
spec:
  containers:
    - name: jiradb
      image: appsacr.azurecr.io/repo:image-version-0.1
      env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: *****
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: dbdata
          subPath: pgdata
  volumes:
    - name: dbdata
      azureDisk:
        kind: Managed
        diskName: temp2
        diskURI: /subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/MC_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/temp2

